# Entrar pra dentro, sair pra fora, subir pra cima e cair pra baixo

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palavras, figuras-de-linguagem

Escuto muitas pessoas falarem:

- *"subir pra cima"*
- *"cair pra baixo"*
- *"entrar pra dentro"*
- *"sair pra fora"*

No entanto isto é considerado "errado" (acredito eu) e tem um nome pra este tipo de frase, mas eu não sei qual seria?

Como isto é chamado?

Comment: Não não é errado e está explicado na resposta.

Comment: Penso que pode até não ser algo errado! Mas, sempre será motivo de troça e estranheza, pelo motivo do óbvio!
Para mim, é como tirar melecas do nariz em público!
Não é meu problema ver alguém fazendo isso.
Mas me causa algum constrangimento, que pode ser evitado!

Answer (score 12):

Esse tipo de expressão é um [pleonasmo (Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasmo).

> O pleonasmo é uma redundância (propositada ou não) numa expressão, enfatizando-a.

Comment: Penso que se deveria inserir na resposta o risco do ridículo de certas redundâncias, sobretudo em discursos ou entrevistas. ‘Vou subir lá para cima’ pode ser alvo de troça, sendo preferível dizer só ‘Vou subir’, ou ‘Vou lá para cima’. Já um verdadeiro pleonasmo, que de facto enfatiza o que se pretende dizer, não o é: ‘Subiu escada acima’, ou ‘Entrou pela casa adentro’, ‘Saiu porta fora’, são expressões comuns que reforçam o sentido.

Comment: Concordo plenamente com @SérgioPereira.   Pleonasmo ou não, essas expressões são condenadas por quem tem instrução e são motivo de troça.  Se um político ou reporter usar alguma delas na TV, vai ser motivo de comentários em toda a mídia no dia seguinte. Pelo menos no Brasil.

Comment: Acho que todos esses "pras" mostram um uso na linguagem falada. As pessoas falam como falam. Os linguistas precisam ter uma visão "mais altiva" desses assuntos.

Answer (score 3):

O nome desta prática é [Pleonasmo Vicioso](https://www.recantodasletras.com.br/gramatica/1188291), e é tido como um *vício de redundância*.

Ao contrário do afirmado em outras respostas, este hábito vai além do simples pleonasmo, e constitui-se em um [vício de linguagem](https://mundoeducacao.bol.uol.com.br/gramatica/vicios-linguagem.htm) que deve ser evitado. Geralmente o interlocutor que exprime tais frases **não está** buscando enfatizar alguma ideia, mas sim está demonstrando **mau uso** da língua, sugerindo um desconhecimento do vocábulo sendo usado. 
Difere assim do uso *estratégico* da redundância, que é intencionalmente explorado na literatura portuguesa: este é denominado de [Pleonasmo Literário](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasmo#Pleonasmo_liter%C3%A1rio), e trata-se de um recurso estilístico que denota uma elevada fluência no idioma.

Os exemplos mais comuns de **pleonasmo vicioso** são inúmeros: decapitar *a cabeça*, conviver *junto*, conclusão *final*, certeza *absoluta*, surpresa *inesperada*, etc.

Comment: muito bom mesmo, comenta sobre o `Pleonasmo Literário`, seria legal demonstrar as diferenças para enriquecer as resposta :) **ps:** vou ser sincero, a recompensa provavelmente já é sua, pois vc me guiou mais e me ajudou a encontrar por mim mesmo ambos tipos, você entendeu bem que aqui a comunidade é sobre português e explicar a parte técnica é o essencial. Obrigado

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Feito! Na verdade, eu sinto um pouco da pressão do "politicamente correto" quando tentam vender aparentes exemplos de "assassinato da língua" como alguma liberdade individual, ou toque pessoal. Mas claro: cabe ao indivíduo (aqui no caso você) construir seu próprio julgamento sobre cada situação.

Comment: E que tal *túnel subterrâneo?* "O curioso é que a estação se acha situada no coração de Manhattan, em plena rua 42, e a gente positivamente não vê por onde entram ou saem os trens. Túneis subterrâneos, galerias e plataformas em vários planos conseguem o milagre de dar ao edifício da Grand Central a repousada aparência de um museu ou de uma casa bancária." Érico Veríssimo, *Gato preto em campo de neve*, 5ª ed,, Porto Alegre, 1944, p. 150.

Answer (score 2):

Errado não é... Quando muito pode ser um **pleonasmo**, o que não significa que *cima*/etc. seja redundante; há um reforço da ideia que é frequentemente importante.

Mas nem sequer é claro que seja o caso dos exemplos muito truncados que dás. Pegando no primeiro exemplo, para mostrar que *cima* nem sempre é redundante:

Em *alguém subir para X*, X pode ser um ponto de destino descrito relativo à posição do locutor. Podemos ter uma frase como:

> Ele subiu lá para baixo.  (dito por alguém num ponto ainda mais alto)

Aqui com *subir* no sentido causativo:

> Subi o quadro três centímetros para cima (e um para a direita).

Mesmo considerando este par de frases, que podem de facto ser equivalentes:

> O gato subiu para o móvel.
>   O gato subiu para cima do móvel.

Podemos imaginar um gato a saltar para uma gaveta aberta de um móvel no primeiro caso, mas dificilmente no segundo.

Por fim, repara que o pleonasmo na primeira frase resulta numa expressividade bem maior do que a segunda frase:

> Subi a rua acima.
>   Subi a rua.

Answer (score 0):

O pleonasmo pode ser um recurso de linguagem a fim de enfatizar a idéia, como na Bíblia em [João 11:41-43 (Almeida Corrigida Fiel](https://www.bibliatodo.com/pt/a-biblia/almeida-corrigida-fiel/joao-11); negrito meu):

> 41. Tiraram, pois, a pedra de onde o defunto jazia. E Jesus, **levantando os olhos para cima**, disse: Pai, graças te dou, por me haveres ouvido.
>       [...]
> 42. E, tendo dito isto, clamou com grande voz: Lázaro, **sai para fora**.

ou Alberto de Oliveira in “Iam Vinte Anos”, citado na [Wikipédia (Pleonasmo)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasmo#Pleonasmo_liter%C3%A1rio):

> Iam vinte anos desde aquele dia,
>   Quando **com os olhos eu quis ver de perto**

Comment: Não entendi, por que o efeito pode ser aceitável? O que a frase tem de relação com isto? A sua argumentação é porque em um livro usaram assim que o torna aceitável? Entende que somos uma comunidade de sobre perguntas de português e esperamos uma explicação mais técnica sobre a abordagem perguntada? Por favor edite a resposta e explique-a melhor. Se tiver duvidas sobre o uso do site recomendo que leia os links em https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help com calma

Comment: Vale mencionar que deve-se tomar cuidado com algum exemplo pontual extraído da Bíblia pode incluir certos artefatos de tradução ou mesmo adulteração em trechos. Além de ser um livro muito antigo, sofreu extensas modificações entre culturas e idiomas, e não envolveu grandes autores do nosso idioma.