# "Ela pegou a bolsa e voltou pra trás" An error? A linguistic vice? A redundancy? Current usage?

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas, redundâncias

In Brazil, the phrase **"voltar pra trás"** is considered just as bad Portuguese as **"entrar pra dentro"** or **"sair pra fora"**.  Many a literate person will turn up the nose if they hear these phrases. In Portugal, however, I've often heard "voltar pra trás" (calm down, I never heard you say "entrar pra dentro" or "sair pra fora") from educated people. There is even a song "Oh tempo, volta pra trás, dá-me tudo que eu perdi..." where the phrase is used.

**Is it considered an error by prescriptivists in Portugal? Is is accepted by descriptivists but considered a redundancy? Or is it just current usage and no purist is shocked on hearing it?**

p.s. There is also the phrase "voltar atrás", which means "to change your decision or opinion" which is current usage in Brazil and perfectly acceptable.
"Ele ia despedir o sub-gerente mas voltou atrás".

EM PORTUGUÊS
No Brasil, a expressão "voltar pra trás" soa tão mal quanto "entrar pra dentro" ou "sair pra fora", pelo menos nos círuclos que frequento. Em Portugal, no entanto, tenho ouvido pessoas letradas usarem-na com relativa frequência. Essa redundância é considerada um erro em Portugal?  É aceita como correta?  Ou choca apenas os puristas?

Comment: Maybe not the answer, but related: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/87/entrar-pra-dentro-sair-pra-fora-subir-pra-cima-e-cair-pra-baixo, and http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/150/o-que-%C3%A9-considerado-pleonasmo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PORTUGUÊS (In English below)**

Eu vou mais longe que o Artefacto: em Portugal, **voltar para trás** está correto e significa *retroceder* (Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa). Por exemplo:

> (a) Vi o João a correr pela rua acima. De repente parou e **voltou para trás.**
>
> (b) Íamos pela estrada velha, mas a ponte ruíra. Tivemos que **voltar para trás** e procurar um caminho alternativo.
>
> (c) Vera ia pela rua acima e encontrou uma bolsa. Então **ela pegou a bolsa e voltou para trás**.

Nos exemplos anteriores não seria possível substituir **voltar para trás** por **voltar**. *Voltar* sem mais complemento nenhum significa *regressar* ao lugar de permanência habitual ou onde se estava antes, como em (d) e (f) abaixo. Nos exemplos acima não há qualquer referência a esse lugar. Apenas se diz que o sujeito começou a deslocar-se em sentido contrário ao anterior. Em *voltar para trás* **voltar** tem o mesmo significado que em *voltar para a direita*. Exemplos do uso de **voltar**:

> (d) Vamos a Londres, **voltamos** no sábado.
>
> (e) Íamos pela estrada velha, mas a ponte ruíra. Tivemos que **voltar à estrada principal** e procurar um caminho alternativo.
>
> (f) Claro que a Vera está aqui. Ela esquecera-se da bolsa no trabalho. Foi lá, **pegou a bolsa e voltou**, há mais de duas horas.

Creio que o OP ao escrever o título da pergunta estava a pensar numa situação como a (f). Em (f) *voltar para trás* estaria incorreto. Nos exemplos (a) a (c) está corretíssimo.

**ENGLISH**

I’ll go further than Artefacto: in Portugal, **voltar para trás** is correct and means **to turn back** (Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa). For instance:

> (a) Vi o João a correr pela rua acima. De repente parou e **voltou para trás**. (I saw João running up the street. Suddenly he stopped and turned back.)
>
> (b) Íamos pela estrada velha, mas a ponte ruíra. Tivemos que **voltar para trás** e procurar um caminho alternativo. (We were going along the old road, but the bridge had collapsed, and we had to turn back and look for another route.)
>
> (c) Vera ia pela rua acima e encontrou uma bolsa. Então **ela pegou a bolsa e voltou para trás**. (Vera was going up the street and found a purse. Then she picked the purse and turned back.)

In the previous exemples it wouldn’t be possible to substitute **voltar** for **voltar para trás**. *Voltar* with no object means to go back to the place where one usually is or where one was before, as in (d) and (f) below. The examples above don’t mention, not even implicitly, such a place. They only state that the agent started going the way they had come. **Voltar** in *voltar para trás* (turn back) means the same as in *voltar para a direita* (turn to the right).  Examples with **voltar**:

> (d) Vamos a Londres, **voltamos** no sábado. (We’re going to London, we’ll come back Saturday.)
>
> (e)  Íamos pela estrada velha, mas a ponte ruíra. Tivemos que **voltar à estrada principal** e procurar um caminho alternativo. (We were going along the old road, but the bridge had collapsed, and we had to go back to the main road and look for another route.)
>
> (f) Claro que a Vera está aqui. Ela esquecera-se da bolsa no trabalho. Foi lá, **pegou a bolsa e voltou**, há mais de duas horas. (Of course, Vera is here. She had forgotten her purse at work. She went there, picked the purse and has come back, over two hours ago.

I reckon the OP in his title was thinking in a situation as in (f). In (f) *voltar para trás* would be incorrect. In the examples (a) to (c) is absolutely correct.

Comment: No, Jacinto, I was thinking about "voltar pra trás" **in any context.**  Many a Brazilian teacher of Portuguese would turn his/her nose up if he/she heard it from a Brazilian.

Comment: Cum laude, as usual.

Comment: Em *Vi o João a correr pela rua acima. De repente parou e voltou*, qual seria o ponto de origem?

Comment: Não se sabe. Se dissesses isso em Portugal, perguntavam-te logo: _voltou para onde?_. Tenho que mudar isso do ponto de origem. Quando nós, em Portugal, dizemos _voltar_ sem mais nada, queremos dizer voltar para junto do locutor ou para o lugar de permanência habitual (casa, posto de trabalho, onde esperarias que ele estivesse nesse momento): _ele não está no gabinete dele? Espera que ele deve voltar já_

Comment: @Centaurus Então qual é a maneira aceitável de exprimir as ideias em (a) a (c) no Brazil?

Comment: Entendi. No Brasil, se disser "voltou", só, em (a) e (c), entende-se que "voltou para trás", "deu meia-volta".

Comment: Sim, é como disse @bfavaretto.  Dizemos simplesmente "parou e voltou" e "pegou a bolsa e voltou".  No Brasil, "pra trás" é considerado um pleonasmo.

Comment: @Centaurus Um pleonasmo bastante utilizado (na fala, na literatura).

Comment: @bfavaretto ptBR do século XXI é bem diferente do ptBR do século XIX ou início do século XX.  Nossos escritores daquela época falavam um português bem mais semelhante ao de Portugal. Ainda não havíamos feito as reformas ortográficas.  Usávamos o "c" entre vogal e "t", e os dois falares eram bem semelhantes.  Hoje em dia é raro ouvir alguém dizer "voltar pra trás" por aqui.

Comment: @Centaurus Ainda é razoavelmente usado por gente menos instruída, o que explica por que soa mal nos registros urbanos mais cultos.

Comment: @bfavaretto  Ah, sim, algumas pessoas com menos instrução ainda dizem "subir pra cima", descer pra baixo".  Mas confesso que "voltar pra trás" só ouço quando vou a Portugal.  Meus parentes Portugueses usam com frequência.  De qualquer forma, eu só conheço 11 dos 27 estados brasileiros. Não posso falar por todos eles.

Answer (score 8):

I can't speak for purists, but *voltar para trás* doesn't shock me at all. Part of the reason is that *voltar* has many meanings, and adding *para trás* helps to disambiguate. Take your sentence:

> Oh tempo, volta pra trás, dá-me tudo que eu perdi...

If you removed *para trás*, the meaning could be subtly different. Telling time to "voltar para trás" means telling it to rewind (*recuar*), whereas "Oh tempo, volta" may be interpreted as you telling a specific period of time to materialize in the current time (*regressar*). In the end, the meaning is not so different in this figurative use, but the mental picture is markedly so.

This happens with other verbs that may mean but don't necessarily mean "go back". Like the other song says "ora arreda lá para trás".